# Php says object is non-object

Tags: php, object, fuelphp

I'm sorry, this is yet another *Trying to get a property of a non-object*-question...

Here's some code and I just can't seem to figure out how this works (or *not* works rather):

```
$b = Model_Artist::query()->where('id', 18)->get_one(); // Fuelphp ORM query, returns \Orm\Model object

var_dump($b); // output: object(Model_Artist)[46] ...  etc.

// definitely an object


var_dump($b->id); // [Error: Trying to get property of non-object] output: '18'

// umm ok, so maybe no object?


var_dump(is_object($b)); // output: bool(true)

// no, no, it is an object!


var_dump($b->id); // [Error: Trying to get property of non-object] output: '18'

// make up your mind, it's no object after all?


if ( is_object($b) ) {
    var_dump($b->id); // output: '18'  [No error!!]
}

// WAT?? It is only an object inside the if statement?
```

So the question is: why does PHP say that I try to get a `property of a non-object` in the first two cases, while `is_object` is `true`. And why does that suddenly change inside the `if` statement?

Either `PHP` is funny, or I'm doing something really really wrong?

Comment: var_dump explores recursively arrays and objects. Maybe it tries to display the value of a "non object" property of your object ? What happens if you just call echo on the id instead of var_dump ?

Comment: I'm thinking that `Model_Artist` has a magic method inside called `__toString()`, this is called when trying to echo or print any values. When you attempt to `var_dump`, it fails.

Comment: which the version you are using? I have tried to reproduce, but unsuccessful.

Comment: The errors show even without `var_dump` or `echo`, just getting `$b->id` triggers the non-object error. Thanks for the suggestions. I use PHP 5.4 with FuelPHP 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

`$b` is an array of objects. and so `$b->id` is not valid but `reset($b)->id` is.